# What types of situations is assembly not fast enough, so you need a direct hardware / boolean logic solution?

Tags: assembly, hardware

I have started to read through [Art of Assembly](https://nostarch.com/assembly2.htm), and in there is a section on boolean logic, which states:

> Of course, it is much easier to specify a solution to a programming problem using languages like Pascal, C, or even assembly language than it is to specify the solution using boolean equations. Therefore, it is unlikely that you would ever implement an entire program using a set of state machines and other logic circuitry. Nevertheless, there are times when a hardware implementation is better. A hardware solution can be one, two, three, or more orders of magnitude faster than an equivalent software solution. Therefore, some time critical operations may require a hardware solution.

In what situations "are there times when a hardware implementation is better"?

Comment: There is a limit to the effective amount of parallelism in any sequentially programmed device.  Going straight to hardware can substantially reduce (though often at considerable expense) the sequential restriction.

Comment: better is a loaded word so this ticket will likely get closed (try programmers.stackexchange).  anything that requires a lot of parallel processing will be faster in hardware, pretty much everything would be faster with dedicated hardware vs programmable hardware (processor, etc).  but "better" requires a list of priorities and guidelines as to what your definition of better is.  strictly faster at any cost, faster for same cost, faster for less cost, maintainable, programmable, etc.  these are only a fraction of the items required to define the word "better"

Comment: Extended discussion: http://yosefk.com/blog/its-done-in-hardware-so-its-cheap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graphics card in your computer would be an excellent example.

Encryption primitives built into the instruction set of your computer's CPU would be another.

Answer (score 3):

There are also special cases where the CPU doesn't have the instructions or the speed to perform specific calculations. One example would be the finite field math operations used on a Raid 6 setup, where Reed Solomon math operations are implemented in special hardware (although some parts of the correction algorithm may be implemented in firmware / software). CRC or other Reed Solomon type error correction codes are often implemented in hardware. Encryption was already mentioned, and AES encryption may have 10 hardware encoders operating in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The [Art of Assembly](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/) may touch a bit on the old-world, where hardware (7400, 4000 series) never failed, and software was "pure magic."

I think what the snippet is hinting at is [Karnaugh Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Put your logic elements into a grid, mark the inputs and output you want, do some gray-code analysis on it, and out pops the simplest logic gate combination to achieve the desired output. Easy to build, very fast, guaranteed to work, and no "magic" involved. To do the equivalent using the processors at that time was slow and cumbersome.